# Compress base64 encoded binary data

Tags: php, http, binary, compression

I'm making an api request for audio files for a language learning app. The request seems to take 2-3 seconds to return, which is far too long for my needs.

I need to pass them back from my php script in the smallest way possible.

How can I send binary data, such as the requested audio file, in the fastest way possible?

Code if needed:

js request:

```
$.get('testPHP.php/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=zh-CN&q=你好',
    function (returned_data) {
        document.getElementById("audio").innerHTML=
            '<embed src="data:audio/mpeg;base64,'+returned_data+'" hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="false"/>';
```

php:

```
$params = http_build_query(array("ie" => $_GET['ie'],"tl" => $_GET["tl"], "q" => $_GET["q"]));
$ctx = stream_context_create(array("http"=>array("method"=>"GET","header"=>"Referer: \r\n"))); 
$soundfile = file_get_contents("https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?".$params, false, $ctx); 

header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');

echo base64_encode($soundfile);
```

Comment: [Enable HTTP compression.](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/speed-up-your-website-with-gzip-compression) Walk away. If this doesn't improve the performance to within acceptable HTTP response sizes - and *it might not due to transferring 'binary'* - then 1) get a faster connection; 2) transfer less data or use an audio/video format with better compression (or accept more encoding loss); or even 3) use a background process or secondary channel to transfer the data.

Comment: @user2864740 can you expand? How do I do this?

Comment: Also, 1) if doesn't need to be base64 encoded that will reduce the size - pre HTTP compression - by about 33%; 2) consider that (ie. test if) `file_get_contents("https://translate.google..")` might be the "slow" part.